# Perform action on <div> depending on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like toggle the class of an element on click but it looks like jQuery only sees what class the element started out as and isn't reading in the change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".red").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("green");
        $(this).removeClass("red");
    });

    $(".green").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("red");
        $(this).removeClass("green");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.green {
    color: green;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="green">I should toggle red/green</p>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I properly toggle the class of an element each time it's clicked?

Comment: Actually it's because you bound the onclick event based on class. Does jQ have a toggleClass() method on its element objects? I know native JS does

Comment: jquery has toggleClass("classname1 classname2")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use `toggleClass()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".red, .green").on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("green red");
    });
});
```

Comment: This. Only does a single select at load, rather than what I'd assume to be an onclick listener to all objects (or at least a listener on document mutation). Also merges the selects into a single statement.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - is the space after "red" in your selector (before the comma) intentional?

Comment: @Stan Not sure if jQ reads it differently, but I know native querySelectorAll() and any valid CSS-style parser should ignore those spaces, meaning they're just for readability.

Comment: @Stan its better to remove it .. but I don't think it wil make defference

Comment: I thought so, but was looking for confirmation - thanks!

Comment: toggleClass("red green")      one can do like this in short try this

Comment: @JohnAnkanna I just tested it before and not worked with me .. but right now its working  https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4jnrzwx5/.. so accept your edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.on`, as you are modifying the classes dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".red", function(){
        $(this).addClass("green");
        $(this).removeClass("red");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".green", function(){
        $(this).addClass("red");
        $(this).removeClass("green");
    });
});
```

Comment: ya that solves the problem of dynamic changing classes.i think we have to add $(document.body)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document.body).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('click',"button",function(){$(this).toggleClass("red green");})
});
</script>
<style>
.red {
    font-size: 120%;
    background: red;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class = "green">Toggle class "green" for p elements</button>

</body>
</html>
```